# Remapping a raster map using GDAL in Python

Tags: python, coordinate-system, gdal, gdalwarp

I have a numpy array of data in Python that is a processed version (outliers set to zero, for example) of data from an Albers Conical United States (US) map:

`PROJCS["Albers Conical Equal Area",GEOGCS["NAD83",DATUM["North_American_Datum_1983",SPHEROID["GRS 1980",6378137,298.257222101,AUTHORITY["EPSG","7019"]],TOWGS84[0,0,0,0,0,0,0],AUTHORITY["EPSG","6269"]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,AUTHORITY["EPSG","8901"]],UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433,AUTHORITY["EPSG","9122"]],AUTHORITY["EPSG","4269"]],PROJECTION["Albers_Conic_Equal_Area"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_center",23],PARAMETER["longitude_of_center",-96],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",29.5],PARAMETER["standard_parallel_2",45.5],PARAMETER["false_easting",0],PARAMETER["false_northing",0],UNIT["meters",1],AXIS["Easting",EAST],AXIS["Northing",NORTH]]`

I would like to take the data points and downsample them so that I can match them up with global weather forecasts, which are typically on an equirectangular projection with, say, pixels every 0.5 degrees.  So most of the globe will be empty -- there will just be some information in the US area.  I would like the information that is downsampled from the US Abers map to the equirectangular globe to be equal either to the average or the sum of the source pixels, depending on the data I'm downsampling.  The source pixels will, of course, not line up directly with the destination pixels.

I have figured out how to do this point-by-point, but it looks like gdal warp can do it for an entire map.  It seems like warp might even be able to do smart things with source pixels that span more than one destination pixel, but it's hard to tell.

Can gdal warp do this operation?  Can it do it from the Python interface?

Comment: I can't give you a full answer now, but i'd recommend you to check `rasterio` and `rasterio.warp`

Comment: Yes and yes....